# cname record and redirection to non-www

Tags: redirect, cname-record

Ive got problem with some case.
1) I set subdomain with CNAME record, its working with some SaaS system outside my server. Its domain without "www" at the beginning, eg. name.domain.com.
2) I tryied to set subdomain with "www" (eg. www.name.domain.com) to my server and redirect it to domain which got CNAME for external server where Saas system is. But it doesnt work that way.
3) I can`t do anything like put htaccess to SaaS server, and I can only setup one adress in that system (now its without "www").

Is it possible to redirect somehow www.name.domain.com to name.domain.com having regard to what I wrote above?

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement the 301 redirect somewhere for the `www` prefix. It might be another server.

Many DNS registrars offer 301 redirection services for domain names.

In both of those cases, you don't use CNAME, but you point the `www` A record to the service replying with `301` status code to the client redirecting to the naked domain.